# finding min&max element in an array (C++)

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the outcome when trying to get max/min element in an array.
the code is :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
  int a, b, max, min;
  cin >> a;
  int arr [a] ;
  max,min = arr[0];
  for (int i; i < a; i++){
    cin >> b;
    arr[i]=b;
    
    if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
    if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
    
    
  }
  cout << min << " " << max ;
  return 0;

  
}
```

input: 5
20 30 40 50 60
output: 0 60

I keep get '0' as an answer for the minimum element. can u see an error with my code?

Comment: WTB some initial values. Insert canned VLA-non-standard C++ spiel here. And yes, there are several errors in your code, at least one of which should be flagging warnings you should be treating as errors. And just fyi, there is zero need for any array for this task. Give it some thought and think about just how important (or not) all the values *except* the running minimum and maximum are at any given moment, and thereafter the loop.

Comment: [Turn on your compiler warnings.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/61zebx)

Comment: This is what `std::minmax_element` algorithm is for. No need to re-invent it.

Comment: Can you explain what you believe is the value of `i` the very first time your `for` loop executes, and why ***exactly*** you believe that's the value of `i` that it starts the loop with?

Comment: You've already set `min` to `arr[0]` value which is zero i believe. Try to use some flag indicating that min is not yet set.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yup i realised i forgot to initialize the value of 'i'

Comment: "You've already set min to arr[0] value" which is NOT ZERO

Comment: @MooingDuck, of course, you are right, there is UB, but even if you zero out that array before assigning the min value, you will still end up with 0, this is what I wanted to note.

Answer (score 3):

Most important: please turn on your compiler warnings. It shows ever mistake in your code:

> :7:7: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'arr'
> [-Wvla]
>
> ```
> 7 |   int arr [a] ;
>   |       ^~~
> ```

`int arr [a];` this declared a VLA (variable length array) because `a` is not a compile-time constant. VLAs are not part of the standard C++, they are an extension of some compilers (most notably gcc, clang).

> :8:3: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect
> [-Wunused-value]
>
> ```
> 8 |   max,min = arr[0];
>   |   ^~~
> ```

This is parsed as `(max, min) = arr[0]`. The comma operator in `max, min` evaluates every operand and the result of the operator is the last operand, i.e. `max` is discarded and only `min` is assigned (incorrectly, see bellow)

> :8:11: warning: '*[0]' is used uninitialized
> [-Wuninitialized]
>
> ```
> 8 |   max,min = arr[0];
>   |       ~~~~^~~~~~~~
> ```

`arr` is uninitialized, so `arr[0]` is uninitialized. You read from an uninitialized object. This is one source of Undefined Behavior.

> :9:12: warning: 'i' may be used uninitialized
> [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
>
> ```
> 9 |   for (int i; i < a; i++){
>   |            ^
> ```

Again, you read from an uninitialized variable `i`.

> :18:25: warning: 'max' may be used uninitialized in this
> function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
>
> ```
> 18 |   cout << min << " " << max ;
>    |                         ^~~
> ```

`max` may be initialized here because of the above.

---

Replace VLAs with standard C++ containers, e.g. `std::vector`

Always initialize your variables. A good rule of thumb is to always initialize your variables when you declare them and declared them as late as possible.

Moreover there is a standard algorithm that finds the min and max in a range: [`std::minmax`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax)

And always use compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` on gcc/clang, `/W3` on MSVC)

Answer (score 2):

By setting your `min` equal to `arr[0]`, you're setting it equal to an undefined value that happens to be 0. You need to read in your first value set and `min` to that, just in case there are no values smaller than 0 and so you don't accidentally end up with odd values.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    int a, b, max, min;
    cin >> a;
    int arr[a];

    // Initializing all values to the first value in the array
    cin >> b;
    min = max = arr[0] = b;

    // Since we already filled out the value at index 0, we start i at 1
    for (int i = 1; i < a; i++) {
        cin >> b;
        arr[i]=b;

        if (arr[i] > max) 
            max = arr[i];
        if (arr[i] < min) 
            min = arr[i];
    }
    cout << min << " " << max ;
    return 0;
}
```

To be entirely honest, you don't even really need an array for this since you're comparing values as you read them in. You could implement it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    int a, b, max, min;
    cin >> a;

    cin >> b;
    min = max = b;

    for (int i = 1; i < a; i++) {
        cin >> b;

        if (b > max) 
            max = b;
        if (b < min) 
            min = b;
    }
    cout << min << " " << max ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "It looks like your compiler is initializing values in your array to 0," no, not really. The program has Undefined Behavior. `arr[a]` you access the array out of bounds, you probably meant `arr[0]`

Comment: @bolov My bad, I was under the impression certain compilers handled undefined array values by setting them to 0. Thank you for drawing my attention to the mistake.

Comment: It's a common misconception that uninitialized variables have "garbage" values. It is much worst than this. On Undefined Behavior the program can have any behavior: it can behave as if the variables was initialized with `0`, it can behave as if the variable was initialized with a random garbage value OR it can crash, it can hang, it can do strange things, it can appear that a variable has two values at the same time, really any behavior, as strange as it might be can happen on UB. Anyway you've got an upvote from me for your effort into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing `min` and `max` with `arr[0]` at a point when `arr[0]` is yet to be initialized. You can fix it by storing first element in  `arr[0]` before using it to initialize `min` and `max`.

If you do proper changes, your code may look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
  int a, b, max, min;
  cin >> a;
  int arr [a] ;
  
  cin >> arr[0];
  max = min = arr[0];
  for (int i=1; i < a; i++){
    cin >> b;
    arr[i]=b;
    
    if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
    if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
  }
  cout << min << " " << max ;
  return 0;
}
```

It is not the perfect code, but it'll work.